# Conditional filtering using grepl and relative row position in group

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, slice, grepl

I have a dataset similar to the following:

```
Journal_ref <- c("1111","2222","2222","2222","3333","3333","4444","4444")
Journal_type <- c("Adj","Rev","Adj","Rev","Rev","Rev","Adj","Adj")
Journal_value <- c(90,10000,12000,80,9000,500,65,2500)
Dataset <- data.frame(Journal_ref,Journal_type,Journal_value)
```

For each `Journal_ref` group I am seeking to filter/select rows based on the following conditions:

- Where "**Adj**" is included within `Journal_type`, filter/select to return the last "**Adj**" row in the `Journal_ref` group, and
- Where "**Adj**" is not included within `Journal_type`, filter/select to return the last "**Rev**" in the `Journal_ref` group

Based on the example above, the final output required would be:

```
Journal_ref Journal_type Journal_value
1111        Adj                    90
2222        Adj                 12000
3333        Rev                   500
4444        Adj                  2500
```

I have attempted using various combinations of `group_by`, `filter`, `if`, `ifelse`, `grepl`, `select` and `slice` with no success.

Any help would be appreciated, particularly using `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

Dataset %>%
  group_by(Journal_ref, Journal_type) %>%
  summarise(Journal_value = last(Journal_value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% group_by(Journal_ref) %>%
  filter(!(n() > 1 & Journal_type == "Rev"))
```

Output:

```
  Journal_ref Journal_type Journal_value
  <fct>       <fct>                <dbl>
1 1111        Adj                     90
2 2222        Adj                  12000
3 3333        Rev                    500
4 4444        Adj                   2500
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution:

```
Dataset %>% 
  group_by(Journal_ref) %>% 
  filter(Journal_type == c("Rev","Adj")[1 + any(Journal_type == "Adj")]) %>% 
  slice(n())
```

which gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 3
> # Groups:   Journal_ref [4]
>   Journal_ref Journal_type Journal_value
>   <fct>       <fct>                <dbl>
> 1 1111        Adj                     90
> 2 2222        Adj                  12000
> 3 3333        Rev                    500
> 4 4444        Adj                   2500
> ```

What this does:

- You group by `Journal_ref`
- Then you filter `Journal_type` for only `Adj` when present and `Rev` when there is no `Adj` in a group. Using `c("Rev","Adj")[1 + any(Journal_type == "Adj")]` gives you `Adj` when there is at least one present in a group and it gives `Rev` when there is no `Adj` present in a group.
- Finally use use `slice(n())` tot select the last row of each group.

---

You could also do this with `if_else`:

```
Dataset %>% 
  group_by(Journal_ref) %>% 
  filter(Journal_type == if_else(any(Journal_type == "Adj"), "Adj", "Rev")) %>% 
  slice(n())
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Many thanks for the explanation also

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` way of doing it is as follows.

```
library(dplyr)

Dataset %>%
  group_by(Journal_ref) %>%
  mutate(Adj = any(Journal_type == "Adj"),
         i = ifelse(Adj, last(which(Journal_type == "Adj")), last(which(Journal_type == "Rev")))) %>%
  filter(row_number() == i) %>%
  select(-Adj, -i)
## A tibble: 4 x 3
## Groups:   Journal_ref [4]
#  Journal_ref Journal_type Journal_value
#  <fct>       <fct>                <dbl>
#1 1111        Adj                     90
#2 2222        Adj                  12000
#3 3333        Rev                    500
#4 4444        Adj                   2500
```